# Integer type for holding function pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, integer, language-lawyer

What standard-defined integer type should I use for holding pointer to functions? Is there a `(void*)`-like type for functions that can hold any functions?

It's very certain that it's not `[u]intptr_t` because the standard said explicitly it's for pointers to objects and the standard makes a clear distinction between pointer to objects and pointer to functions.

Comment: I believe it's guaranteed safe to cast between function pointers of any type, so you can use `void (*)()` as your replacement for `void *`.  I don't know of an integer type.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's not fully standard-conforming. That type is a function type without prototype, and in "Future language directions" the standard says: "The use of function declarators without prototypes is an obsolescent feature"

Comment: "Obsolecent" is still confoming for now, though, right?  If you prefer, use `void (*)(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specified type for an integer type that is sufficient to encode a function pointer.

Alternatives:

- Change code to negate the need for that integer type.  Rarely is such an integer type truly needed.
- Use an array: `unsigned char[sizeof( int (*)(int)) )]` and `int (*f)(int))`  within `union` to allow some examination of the integer-ness of the pointer.  Still there may be padding issues.  Comes down to what code want to do with such an integer.
- Use `uintmax_t` and *hope* it is sufficient.  A `_Static_assert(sizeof (uintmax_t) >= sizeof (int (*)(int)) );` is a reasonable precaution though not a guarantee of success.

---

The limiting spec

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type. C17dr § 6.3.2.3 6

---

Note even `[u]intptr_t` for object pointer types are a guarantee either as they are optional types.

Comment: The `intmax` part is same as what I thought. If the standard committee sees this, hope they'll amend the standard for it, and I expect newer answers be available in the future.

Comment: I seriously object the "Use an array" part. It's slaughtering a chicken with a bull butcher's knife.

Comment: @DannyNiu Consider platform where all function pointers are 128 bit and the largest integer type is 64.  Yet this begs the question, what do you intend to do with a function pointer converted to an integer?

Comment: Well, I'm experimenting with macro- and function- based meta-objects that returns information about hash functions, such as its block/output size, init/update/final functions. These information are mixed together, and hence the need.

Comment: @DannyNiu Using an `union` and `unsigned char` array / function pointer  is a compliant portable way to print the value of a function pointer.  The interpretation of that output is implementation defined, yet code is complaint.  I know of no other complaint way to print a function pointer  - effectively a memory dump.

Comment: @DannyNiu Per your need, code could roughly use a  `struct int type; union { int (*)(int) fp; void *vp; uintmax_t u; long double ld; ...}`.  To fully address your real need, perhaps post that as a question with details?

Comment: Appreciated, `uintmax_t` and `size_t` will work for me. I don't intend this to be an XY question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `memcpy` works, and has the advantage of *also* working in C++, where the union does not.

Answer (score 2):

> It's very certain that it's not `[u]intptr_t`

It's true. But the distinction is **only** made to guarantee the correctness of some essential conversions. If you look at the 2nd edition of "The C Programming Language", then the distinction is more subtle to notice than the current wording in the standard.

If you target platforms with operating systems, then `[u]intptr_t` is probably *exactly* what you want, as:

1. POSIX specifies `dlsym` function that returns `void *` with the requirement that result can be casted to function pointers and be usable.
2. Win32 [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) is defined in such way that, if the return values' not NULL, it'll be a valid memory address that's valid for functions and/or objects.